# How do I receive push notifications with socket.IO-client?

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io, client

My goal is to get push notifications from the web site (it provides socketIO interface). In order to do that I use socket.io-client library. I took the code from some socket.io examples. Here it is:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

socket = io.connect('https://cryptonit.net', {
    port: 8080
});

socket.on('connect', function() { 
    console.log('connected');
 });

socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected');
});

socket.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('System', e ? e : 'A unknown error occurred');
});
```

But I don't get any messages, neither I see that connection was established. What can be the possible source of the problem? How can I test this code?

Actually all examples I've seen were supposed to connect to the localhost, not to the real website.

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? You're using require, which indicates that this is server side code, not client side. Unless you're using something like Browserify.

Comment: There's a website I want to get push notifications from. As far as I understand this site (exchange) should run a server and I need to make a client to connect to its socket. Socket.io-client allows me to avoid using browser, so I run this code in terminal. Is it impossible to use require in this case?

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to use socket.io to connect to someone elses websocket from node.js directly. Not from a browser? Are they using socket.io?

Comment: That's right! Yeah, they provide socketIO interface. As I understand using browser is optional: socket.io-client allows to avoid it and personally I like working in terminal but I also tried to make a script adding socketIO dependencies. It didn't help, so probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Try running your app using `DEBUG=* node app.js`. This will enable all debug logs in socket.io, and might help you track down where the problem is.

Comment: Okey, it stops at line 4. Something's wrong with a port? But I'm sure it's 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change

```
socket = io.connect('https://cryptonit.net', {
    port: 8080
});
```

to

```
socket = io.connect('https://cryptonit.net:8080');
```

to get it working.

Have no idea why the first one is wrong.